# Plotting multiple columns to X-axis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping

I'm finishing my Google Data Analytics capstone and struggling to find the correct way to map a data frame.(or if it's even possible)

I have 4 columns with numerical data showing activity levels. I want to create a bar chart and plot all 4 separately on the X-axis to show the difference between them. They are all located on the same data frame and each column is beside one another. They all share the same datatype and range, so I shouldn't have to plot the y-axis.

However, I am unsure the correct syntax to do this. I'll do my best to include as much as possible but please let me know if there is anything else to include. Thank you for your help!

```
ggplot(data = activity) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=VeryActiveMinutes:SedentaryMinutes))
```

> Error in `geom_bar()`:
> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
> ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (940)
> ✖ Fix the following mappings: `x`
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> Warning messages:
> 1: In VeryActiveMinutes:SedentaryMinutes :
> numerical expression has 940 elements: only the first used
> 2: In VeryActiveMinutes:SedentaryMinutes :
> numerical expression has 940 elements: only the first used

Comment: Hi Rory! You'll likely get better, faster help by editing your question to include the code to reproduce your data (typically best to include the output of `dput(activity)` or something like `dput(head(activity, 20))` if its really big). Good luck!

Comment: `ggplot2` works with "tidy" aka longer data, where each aesthetic (such as "which series") is specified in a single column. You probably want something like `tidyr::pivot_longer(activity, VeryActiveMinutes:SedentaryMinutes) |> ggplot(aes(name, value)) + geom_col()`

Comment: This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format. See bar plot examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74704993/plotting-a-graph-with-multiple-bars-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73956741/how-do-i-create-a-clustered-chart-using-position-dodge-in-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, `ggplot2` and friends do much better when given "tidy" data, more viewed in a "long" format than wide. For instance,

```r
wide <- data.frame(a=1, b=11, d=21, e=31)
wide
#   a  b  d  e
# 1 1 11 21 31
tidyr::pivot_longer(wide, cols = b:e)
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#       a name  value
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 b        11
# 2     1 d        21
# 3     1 e        31
```

The latter is preferred. There are many ways to reshape it, including `tidyr::pivot_longer` (shown above), `reshape2::melt`, and very similar `data.table::melt`. (The above works with multiple rows as well, not just one row, though handling the `geom_bar` below will be different.

From there, you have just a single "value" variable. Perhaps this works for you:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(activity, cols = VeryActiveMinutes:SedentaryMinutes) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = name, y = value), stat = "identity")
```

Comment: I needed to reshape my data frame. I knew it was something! Thank you to everyone for your help and guidance!